# Are there any other options for rest clients besides CURL?

Tags: php, rest

Are there alternatives to CURL in PHP that will allow for a client to connect o a REST architecture server ?

PUT, DELETE, file upload are some of the things that need to work.

Comment: cURL is not PHP specific, and libcurl could be added to your project http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

Comment: it's not specific but it's easy to install and use. Similar solution are a good answer.

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use cURL?

Comment: I need something easy to install and generic so the clients don't have to rely on a single library in order to use the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own library. It's even possible to do it completely in PHP, using [fsockopen](http://php..net/fsockopen) and friends. For example:

```
function httpget($host, $uri) {
  $msg = 'GET '.$uri." HTTP/1.1\r\n".
         'Host: '.$host."\r\n".
         "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
  $fh = fsockopen($host, 80);
  fwrite($fh, $msg);
  $result = '';
  while(!feof($fh)) {
    $result .= fgets($fh);
  }
  fclose($fh);
  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Zend_Http_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.html) (from Zend) or [HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/) (from PEAR). They both provide a well-designed object model for making HTTP requests.

In my personal experience, I've found the Zend version to be a little more mature (mostly in dealing with edge cases).