# PHP get_headers() alternative

Tags: php, http-headers, httpresponse

I need a  PHP script that reads the HTTP response code for each URL request.

something like

```
$headers = get_headers($theURL);
return substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
```

The problem is the get_headers() function is disabled at server level, as a policy.So it doesn't work.

The question is how to get the HTTP response code for a URL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If cURL is enabled, you can use it to get the whole header or just the response code. The following code assigns the response code to the `$response_code` variable:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://stackoverflow.com' ) );
curl_exec( $curl );
$response_code = curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
curl_close( $curl );
```

To get the whole header you can issue a HEAD request, like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://stackoverflow.com' ) );
$headers = explode( "\n", curl_exec( $curl ) );
curl_close( $curl );
```

Comment: @Matej Yeah it works well, but a simple note on that,i think we won't get the "server" what they're using like "Apache or iis etc.," and some other details. but to check server response code it works well.

Comment: @Sekar: The `Server` is optional, it depends on the server if it sends it or not.

Answer (score 4):

Use HttpRequest if you can: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php

```
$request = new HttpRequest("http://www.example.com/");
$request->send();
echo $request->getResponseCode();
```

Or do it the hard way: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

```
$errno = 0;
$errstr = "";

$res = fsockopen('www.example.com', 80, $errno, $errstr);

$request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$request .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
$request .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

fwrite($res, $request);

$head = "";

while(!feof($res)) {
    $head .= fgets($res);
}

$firstLine = reset(explode("\n", $head));
$matches = array();
preg_match("/[0-9]{3}/", $firstLine, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Curl may be also a good option, but the best option is to beat your admin ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can build and read your own HTTP queries with [fsockopen](http://php.net/fsockopen) and regular file operations. Check out my earlier answer on this topic:

[Are there any other options for rest clients besides CURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864992/are-there-any-other-options-for-rest-clients-besides-curl/5865093#5865093)

Comment: +1, but if he has curl available that's probably easier to write and maintain than rolling your own.