# wrapper_data is empty?

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

I have a php script to retrieve headers using cURL, as described on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087222/php-get-headers-alternative) link.  This works great on a localhost, but when I try to run the exact same script on another host, it will return a similar array, except for the array `wrapper_data` which is unfortunately the section I need (I'm trying to figure out if a url is an mp3 file).

Local returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
Array
(
    [wrapper_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
            [1] => Server: nginx
            [2] => Date: Thu, 14 Jul 2011 02:46:34 GMT
            [3] => Content-Type: audio/mpeg
            [4] => Connection: close
            [5] => Last-Modified: Thu, 22 Oct 2009 16:19:38 GMT
            [6] => Expires: Fri, 13 Jul 2012 02:46:34 GMT
            [7] => Content-Length: 5103556
            [8] => X-hawt: very
            [9] => X-Orig-Src: 0_mogord
            [10] => X-nc: HIT ord 9
            [11] => Accept-Ranges: bytes
            [12] => Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
        )

    [wrapper_type] => http
    [stream_type] => tcp_socket/ssl
    [mode] => r
    [unread_bytes] => 0
    [seekable] => 
    [uri] => http://takethesongsandrun.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/proud-graduates.mp3
    [timed_out] => 
    [blocked] => 1
    [eof] =>
```

but the host returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
Array
(
    [wrapper_data] => Array
        (
            [headers] => Array
                (
                )

            [readbuf] => Resource id #14
        )

    [wrapper_type] => cURL
    [stream_type] => cURL
    [mode] => r
    [unread_bytes] => 0
    [seekable] => 
    [uri] => http://thedadada.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/06-pulling-on-a-line.mp3
    [timed_out] => 
    [blocked] => 1
    [eof] =>
```

I know cURL is not the problem, as it works in other places on my site. Is there something preventing this information from being retrieved properly?

Answer (score 0):

What I discovered is that the cUrl wrapper won't return the headers until you've used fread() on the handle