# Any replacement for get_header in php?

Tags: php

I am creating a function which crawls links from a page. 
Now there can be different ways of specifying links in href tag..

1) http://example.com

2) http://www.example.com

3) example.com

4) files/downloads

5) www.example.com

Now here the 1), 2) and 5) are in proper format. 
But before adding 3) and 4) i want to make them in proper url format...

which means 3) should become http://example.com and 4) should become

http:// THECURRENTPAGEURLDOMAIN /files/download

I am using get_headers to differentiate between a relative and independent URL. So if i test headers for example.com by appending http:// in front, it would return some headers and

if i test headers for files/download by same method , it would return failed to open stream instead of some false value which i can use to know that its a relative url.

So why get_headers isnt returning false value. It is giving warning about failed to open stream.

Answer (score 1):

```
1- you should have the base your, e.g: example.com
2- check if th url is not a url, then the append it to the base url

is_url($url)
{
    return (bool) filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED);
}

$url = '/files/download';
$base_url = 'http://example.com';
if !is_url($url) {
   $url = rtrim($base_url, '/') . '/' . ltrim($url, '/');
}

// continue your code ....
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`curl()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for faster response use curl

For more info :- [PHP get_headers() alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087222/php-get-headers-alternative)